# NSTextField draws white area after resigning first responder

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit

I got an NSTextField that looks just fine until it resigns the first responder.

[image]

It draws a white rectangle until it becomes the first responder again. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Are you using any heavy-lifting code on the main thread blocking the UI? And another thought is, are you using layer backed/hosted views and getting the right layer updates if you are? (i.e. layerContentsRedrawPolicy) etc...

Comment: I'm not blocking the main thread, but I'm using Core Animation so the view is layer backed as a matter of cause. The bug still occurs if I change the redraw policy.

Comment: try setting (swift)`theNSTextField.drawsBackground = true` or (Obj-C)`[theNSTextField setDrawsBackground: YES]`

Comment: If I enable it in IB, Xcode automatically unchecks the checkbox. If I do it in code, drawsBackground returns false after I set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

The drawing issue seems to be caused by the TextField's cell and not by the TextField itself. This weird workaround fixes the issue:

```
class TextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

    override func drawInteriorWithFrame(cellFrame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView) {
        super.drawInteriorWithFrame(cellFrame, inView: controlView)
    }

}
```

Comment: This resolves the background color issue, but it causes the placeholder text to disappear from the non-focused text fields.